# issue with calling Fragment class' method

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a class "HomeActivity", which is as follows:

```
        public class HomeActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener {

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

                // Create the list fragment and add it as our sole content.
                if (fm.findFragmentById(android.R.id.content) == null) {
                    HomeFragment list = new HomeFragment();
                    fm.beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, list).commit();

                }
            }
        public static class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

        webServiceTask = WebServiceTask.getInstance(
                                    getActivity(), Constants.METHOD_NAME_PRODUCTS,
                                    Constants.PRODUCT_NAME, null);

public  void Work() {}
    }
    }
```

I have another class WebServiceTask, which is as follows:

```
  final public class WebServiceTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    private WebServiceTask(final Activity activity, final String methodName,
                final String productName, final String addInfo[]) {
            super();
            this.activity = activity;
            this.methodName = methodName;
            this.productName = productName;
            this.addInfo = addInfo;
        }
public static WebServiceTask getInstance(final Activity activity,
            final String methodName, final String productName,
            final String additionalInfo[]) {
        webServiceTask = new WebServiceTask(activity, methodName, productName,
                additionalInfo);
        return webServiceTask;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute() {

    // Here I am trying to call the work() method in HomeFragment, How can I do that?
    }
```

My question is how can i call the work() method in HomeFragment class from onPostExecute().

Comment: work method is in HomeFragment class. Also i have activity variable.

Comment: ohh i didn't see that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would propose making a listener for you task, and invoke its method in post execute. It will geve you a lot more flexibility and control on what you want to deafter the task finishes. Here is sample code I would use:

```
public class MyTask extend AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    public interface MyTaskListener {
         void onSuccess();
         void onFailure();
         void onError(Throwable t);
    }

    private Throwable error;
    private MyTaskListener listener;


    public MyTask(MyTaskListener listener) {
          this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Overrride
    public Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
            if (workCompleted()) { 
                //work completed without error - return true
                return Boolean.TRUE;
            } else {
                //work failed to complete - return false
                return Boolean.FALSE;
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            //unexpected error  happened - remember error and return null
            this.error = e;
            return null;
        }  


    }


    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(Boolean result){
         if (!isCancelled()) { //you only want to process if task wasn't cancelled

             if (this.error != null && result == null) { //we have error, process it
                 if (listener != null) {
                     listener.onError(this.error);
                 }
             }

             if (Boolean.FALSE.equals(result)) { //we have faile, process it
                 if (listener != null) {
                     listener.onFail();
                 }
             }

             if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(result)) { //we have success
                 if (listener != null) {
                     listener.onSuccess();
                 }
             }


         }
    }


}
```

And then, in you activit/fragment/service/ use something like this:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {


    private void someInstanceMethod() {/ *do your work here */}

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

          //setup ui, or do whatever you need

          //create MyAsyncTask with proper listener
          MyAsyncTask task = new MyAsyncTask(new MyAsyncTask.MyAsyncTaskListener() {

              @Override
              public void onSuccess() {
                  //call your instance method here
                  someInstanceMethod();

              }

              @Override
              public void onFailure() {
                  //process fail
              }

              @Override
              public void onError() {
                  //process error
              }


          });



    } 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one method. I don't know if it is the best one:

Make work function as public **static** void. Call it from Asynctask onpostexecute as

```
HomeActivity.Work();
```

Edit:
*One more way( again not sure if this is the best way)*:

If you cant make this work, consider putting your asynctask class *inside* the home activity class

Comment: cant make that static. I am using click listeners in the method

Answer (score 0):

Well using the `FragmentManger` `findFragmentById()` or `findFragmentByTag()` you can get an instance of the current fragment and call your fragment method.

Comment: How can i get the Id in my case?

Comment: Try to bring the AsyncTask as inner class inside HomeActivity, make the FragmentManager a class variable, now you have access to fragment manager anywhere you want.

Answer (score 0):

Create an interface file

```
public interface AsynAction
{
  public void Work();
}
```

Implements AsynAction in HomeActivity

```
public class HomeActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener,AsyncAction {

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

                // Create the list fragment and add it as our sole content.
                if (fm.findFragmentById(android.R.id.content) == null) {
                    HomeFragment list = new HomeFragment();
                    fm.beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, list).commit();

                }
            }
        public static class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

        webServiceTask = WebServiceTask.getInstance(
                                    getActivity(), Constants.METHOD_NAME_PRODUCTS,
                                    Constants.PRODUCT_NAME, null);
@Override
public  void Work() 
          {
          }
    }
    }
```

Then make changes in you asynctask to receive asyncAction object as reference

```
final public class WebServiceTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    private WebServiceTask(final AyscAction asycAction,final Activity activity, final String methodName,
                final String productName, final String addInfo[]) {
            super();
            this.activity = activity;
            this.asycAction=asycAction;
            this.methodName = methodName;
            this.productName = productName;
            this.addInfo = addInfo;
        }
public static WebServiceTask getInstance(final AyscAction asycAction,final Activity activity,
            final String methodName, final String productName,
            final String additionalInfo[]) {
        webServiceTask = new WebServiceTask(asycAction,activity, methodName, productName,
                additionalInfo);
        return webServiceTask;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute() {

    // You can call work from here
       if(asynAction!=null)
          asyncAction.Work();
    }
```